# Make a second child element comply with parent height and not overlap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with second child element `section.nested` overstepping parent div height.
I've tried and tried but can't make it to comply with the parent `div` any ideas?

```css
html,body,main {
  height: 100%
}
main {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

main > section {
    min-width: 31%;
    max-width: 74%;
    max-height: 74%;
    padding: 1.27rem;
    background-color: #575757;
}

main > section > div {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

main section.nested {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

article {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #eee
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div>
      <header>
        <h3>heading</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </header>
      <section class="nested">
        <div>
          <article></article>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>  
  <section>
</main>
```

I'm interested in just `section.nested` to comply without giving explicit `px` heights the rest of the overflow doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

remove  **max-height: 74%;** property from  **main > section**

```css
html,body,main {
  height: 100%
}
main {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

main > section {
    min-width: 31%;
    max-width: 74%;
    padding: 1.27rem;
    background-color: #575757;
}

main > section div {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

main section.nested {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

article {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #eee
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div>
      <header>
        <h3>heading</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </header>
      <section class="nested">
        <div>
          <article></article>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>  
  <section>
</main>
```

Comment: No, I need that to stay

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve here. but add **overflow-y: scroll;** to  **main > section > div**

Answer (score 0):

## Shorter Article Option

Removing `height: 600px;` from the `article` selector prevents that article from overflowing the parent.

```css
html,body,main {
  height: 100%
}
main {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

main > section {
    min-width: 31%;
    max-width: 74%;
    max-height: 74%;
    padding: 1.27rem;
    background-color: #575757;
}

main > section > div {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

main section.nested {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

article {
  background-color: #eee
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div>
      <header>
        <h3>heading</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </header>
      <section class="nested">
        <div>
          <article>Some things in here?</article>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>  
  </section>
</main>
```

## Taller Section Option

If you want to keep the 600px height of the article then you need to remove `max-height: 74%;` from the `main > section` selector.

```css
html,body,main {
  height: 100%
}
main {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

main > section {
    min-width: 31%;
    max-width: 74%;
    padding: 1.27rem;
    background-color: #575757;
}

main > section > div {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

main section.nested {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

article {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div>
      <header>
        <h3>heading</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </header>
      <section class="nested">
        <div>
          <article>Some things in here?</article>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>  
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Yeah I know that but that's not the point :)
That height simulates content and I'm interested in just `section.nested` to comply the rest of the overflow doesn't matter :)

Comment: Then the second example is what you're after, removing the max-height on the section :)

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that but unfortunately can't spare that `max-height:74%` that's why I ended up here asking for help :(

Comment: Another option would be to make the article content scroll within the section. What is that max-height 74% doing for you? There could be another way to achieve what that rule is doing